# socket io in C# streamlabs SocketIoClientDotNet

Tags: c#, socket.io

I've been trying to connect to streamlabs' socket api with C#. I found this library SocketIoClientDotNet that prommised to be really easy but it just doesn't work.

I took the example code from github added a bunch of events to see what'll happen and not a sigle event ever fires, not even the error ones. there is activity in wireshark, but I can't see it because it's encrypted

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start");
       string key = "";
        var socket = IO.Socket("https://sockets.streamlabs.com/socket.io/?token=+ key");

        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, (data) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("connect error");
        });

        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, (data) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
        });

        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_MESSAGE, (data) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("msg");
        });


        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, (data) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("timeout");
        });

        socket.On("event", (data) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("event");
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

the JS equvalent code works ok

Comment: Where is the data variable defined?

Comment: no idea, I followed the example https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet

Comment: are you using asp.net core 2+?

Comment: it doesn't say anywhere that I should.

Comment: I tested it with https://socket-io-chat.now.sh and it works, so it must be the streamlabs implementation. I guess I have to figure out how to get rid of ssl

Comment: I found the issue, the c# lib is based on version 1.1.0  of socket io, I need to use 2.0.3